# Python 3: handling numpy arrays and export via openpyxl

Tags: numpy, python-3.5, openpyxl

I am working with an array consisting of several lists. Of each sublist, I want to take the mean and the std. deviation, and write them in an excel sheet.

The code I have does its job, but it gives me headache as I feel I'm not using python efficiently at all, especially in step (2), where I use numpy in a step-by-step manner. Also, I don't get why I have to do the modification in step (3) in order to bring the data ("total") in a form that I can feed to the openpyxl writer ("total_list"). I would appreciate any help in making it more elegant, here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import Workbook
from itertools import chain

# (1) Make up sample array:
arr = [[1,1,3], [3,4,2], [4,4,5], [6,6,5]]

# (2) Make up lists containing average values and std. deviations
avg = []
dev = []

for i in arr:
    avg.append(np.mean(i))
    dev.append(np.std(i))

# (3) Make an alternating list (avg 1, dev 1, avg 2, dev 2, ...)
total = chain.from_iterable( zip( avg, dev ) )

# (4) Make an alternative list that can be fed to the xlsx writer
total_list = []
for i in total:
    total_list.append(i)

# Write to Excel file
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws.append(total_list)
wb.save("temp.xlsx")
```

I would like to have the format shown in the picture attached. It is important, that all data are in one row. [image: Desired Output Format]

Comment: could you post a desired data set? In which shape would you like to have it?

Comment: What problems are you experiencing when you try to do this? openpyxl supports numpy types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improvements on the numpy code:

```
In [272]: arr = [[1,1,3], [3,4,2], [4,4,5], [6,6,5]]
```

Make an array from this list.  This isn't required since `np.mean` does it under the covers, but it should help visualize the action.

```
In [273]: arr = np.array(arr)
In [274]: arr
Out[274]: 
array([[1, 1, 3],
       [3, 4, 2],
       [4, 4, 5],
       [6, 6, 5]])
```

Now calculate mean and std for the whole array; use `axis=1` to act on rows.  So you don't to iterate on the sublists of `arr`.

```
In [277]: m=np.mean(arr, axis=1)
In [278]: s=np.std(arr, axis=1)
In [279]: m
Out[279]: array([ 1.66666667,  3.        ,  4.33333333,  5.66666667])
In [280]: s
Out[280]: array([ 0.94280904,  0.81649658,  0.47140452,  0.47140452])
```

There are various ways of turning these 2 arrays into the interleaved array.  One is to stack them vertically, and then transpose.  This is the `numpy` answer to the list `zip(*...)` trick.

```
In [281]: data=np.vstack([m,s])
In [282]: data
Out[282]: 
array([[ 1.66666667,  3.        ,  4.33333333,  5.66666667],
       [ 0.94280904,  0.81649658,  0.47140452,  0.47140452]])
In [283]: data=data.T.ravel()
In [284]: data
Out[284]: 
array([ 1.66666667,  0.94280904,  3.        ,  0.81649658,  4.33333333,
        0.47140452,  5.66666667,  0.47140452])
```

I don't have `openpyxl', but can write a csv with`savetxt`:

```
In [296]: np.savetxt('test.txt',[data],fmt='%f', delimiter=',',header='#mean1 std1 ...')
In [297]: cat test.txt

# #mean1 std1 ...
1.666667,0.942809,3.000000,0.816497,4.333333,0.471405,5.666667,0.471405
```

I used `[data]` because `data`, as calculated is 1d, and `savetxt` would save that as a column.  It iterates on the 'rows' of data.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Pandas module, as it can do all mentioned tasks pretty easy:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

In [250]: df
Out[250]:
   0  1  2
0  1  1  3
1  3  4  2
2  4  4  5
3  6  6  5

In [251]: df.T
Out[251]:
   0  1  2  3
0  1  3  4  6
1  1  4  4  6
2  3  2  5  5

In [252]: df.T.mean()
Out[252]:
0    1.666667
1    3.000000
2    4.333333
3    5.666667
dtype: float64

In [253]: df.T.std(ddof=0)
Out[253]:
0    0.942809
1    0.816497
2    0.471405
3    0.471405
dtype: float64
```

you can also easily save your DataFrame as Excel file:

```
df.to_excel(r'/path/to/file.xlsx', index=False)
```

Altogether:

```
In [260]: df['avg'] = df.mean(axis=1)

In [261]: df['dev'] = df.std(axis=1, ddof=0)

In [262]: df
Out[262]:
   0  1  2       avg       dev
0  1  1  3  1.666667  0.816497
1  3  4  2  3.000000  0.707107
2  4  4  5  4.333333  0.408248
3  6  6  5  5.666667  0.408248

In [263]: df.to_excel('d:/temp/result.xlsx', index=False)
```

result.xlsx:

[image]

Comment: FWIW openpyxl can now handle Dataframe objects which gives users more control over the output.

Comment: @CharlieClark, can you share some links to new features (examples)?